# How to make wx.statictext text transparent in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import wx, wx.media
import sqlite3
import os
import time

class MainFream(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.leftPanel = wx.Panel(self, size=(0,0))
        self.media = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self,
                                        #szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER,
                                        szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10,
                                        size = (0,0),
                                        style = wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        image = wx.Image('1.bmp', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.background = wx.StaticBitmap(self.leftPanel, 0, image, (0,0))


        self.hBoxSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.hBoxSizer.Add(self.leftPanel, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.hBoxSizer.Add(self.media, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(self.hBoxSizer)

        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        self.mediaCounter = 0
        self.folderSerach = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith(('.mpg', '.jpg', '.wmv'))]
        self.media.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.mediaPlay, self.media)
        self.media.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.mediaLoop, self.media)
        self.media.Load(self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter])

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.autoRefresh, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(10000)

        self.Text()
        self.LoadText()
        self.TextSizer()

    def autoRefresh(self, event):
        self.LoadText()

    def mediaPlay(self, event):
        if self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter].endswith('jpg'):
            self.media.Play()
            #time.sleep(10)
        else:
            self.media.Play()

    def mediaLoop(self, evnet):
        self.media.Stop()
        self.mediaCounter += 1
        print(self.folderSerach)
        if self.mediaCounter > len(self.folderSerach) -1: self.mediaCounter = 0
        self.media.Load(self.folderSerach[self.mediaCounter])

    def Text(self):
        self.title = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, label='test title', style=wx.EXPAND)

        self.staticText1_1 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, label="test1", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_2 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, label="test2", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_3 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, label="test3", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_4 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, label="test4", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_5 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, label="test5", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText1_6 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, label="test6", style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.staticText2_1 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_2 = TransparentText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_3 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_4 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_5 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.staticText2_6 = wx.StaticText(self.leftPanel, style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

    def LoadText(self):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT *FROM CLINIC1")
        for data1 in self.cursor.fetchall(): pass
        self.staticText2_1.SetLabel(data1[1])
        self.staticText2_2.SetLabel(data1[2])
        self.staticText2_3.SetLabel(data1[3])
        self.staticText2_4.SetLabel(data1[4])
        self.staticText2_5.SetLabel(data1[5])
        self.staticText2_6.SetLabel(data1[6])

    def TextSizer(self):
        self.gridSizer = wx.GridSizer(3, 6, 0, 5)
        self.textSizers = (
            self.staticText1_1, self.staticText1_2, self.staticText1_3,
            self.staticText1_4, self.staticText1_5, self.staticText1_6,
            self.staticText2_1, self.staticText2_2, self.staticText2_3,
            self.staticText2_4, self.staticText2_5, self.staticText2_6,
        )
        for textSizer in self.textSizers:
            self.gridSizer.Add(textSizer, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 1)
        self.vttextSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.vttextSizer.Add(self.title, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.TOP, 1)
        self.vttextSizer.Add(self.gridSizer, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 1)
        self.leftPanel.SetSizer(self.vttextSizer)

class TransparentText(wx.StaticText):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='', pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                 size=wx.DefaultSize, style=wx.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW, name=''):
        wx.StaticText.__init__(self, parent, id, label, pos, size, style, name)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, lambda event: None)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.on_size)

    def on_paint(self, event):
        bdc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc = wx.GCDC(bdc)

        font_face = self.GetFont()
        font_color = self.GetForegroundColour()

        dc.SetFont(font_face)
        dc.SetTextForeground(font_color)
        dc.DrawText(self.GetLabel(), 0, 0)

    def on_size(self, event):
        self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    fream = MainFream()
    fream.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]
I made the text letters transparent behind the background. The problem is that if you update automatically, the transparent part disappears like the attached picture.

The result is the same using `wx.CallLater`. Is there a problem with my code?
I do not know why. Overlay phenomenon?

Comment: There does not appear to be an issue with your code. It works on Linux. The issue must be with wx and your OS.

Comment: Thank you every time. When I tested it on Linux, `class TransparentText (wx.StaticText):` I get transparent text without using it. Why is it different on Windows? Is there any difference in expressing it according to `szBackend` setting?

Comment: No the backend relates only to the method used to "play" the media. The issue relates to the display. I have found that sometimes,on Linux, the theme used for the display can effect how things both look and operate. Using theme Mint-X for example will not allow coloured buttons but other themes do. I have never found out why.

Comment: It has to do with the native widgets on the OS. Some operating systems allow transparency in their native widgets while others do not. wxPython uses the native widgets. If you want to do something different, then you will need to use a custom widget or switch to something that draws all its widgets, like Tkinter or PyQt.